Is it true that engines built in Russia are still used to launch American spacecraft?
Is it true that today's launch of the American spacecraft Boeing Starliner still used Russian-made engines?

Yes. That is going to end soon though: US companies have been unable to buy new engines from Russia for a few years now so once existing stock is gone, alternatives have to be found. ULA has developed a successor to the Atlas V that uses US-made engines.

Yes.  See any number of sources, including ULA's page on the Starliner CFT launch, under the production section, stating that the RD-180s for the Atlas V are made at NPO Energomash, Khimki, Russia.

Though they stopped buying them sometime in 2021 or so, and started moving away from them in 2014.

Thanks a lot! I admire your precise reference to such an authoritative source (and it actually says “Russia”).

The Antares 110/120/130 (Larger upper stages change the model number) booster that launched the first few Cygnus capsules were using Russian NK-33 engines that were built in the 1970's for the N-1 booster but not used.  They were bought by Aerojet, refurbished and renamed the AJ-26. Each booster used two. These use Kerosene and LOX to fly.
However on the fifth launch the engines failed and the booster was lost.
So Northrup Grumman moved over to using a pair of Russian RD-181 engines (quarter of the RD-170 used on the Zenit booster, which was originally the strapon booster (4 per launch) of the Energia rocket). The RD-170, 180, 181 family all use Kerosene and LOX to fly.
This too ended with the Ukraine invasion and now they are waiting for Firefly to deliver them Miranda engines, which will fly 7 on the first stage. Which will also use Kerosene and LOX to fly.
As noted by others, Atlas 3 and 5 used the RD-180 engine (half of the RD-170) as its main engine. There are quite a number stockpiled in the US before the troubles in Ukraine.  The last dozen or so Atlas V launches will use those stockpiled engines.
The future for ULA is Vulcan which is using Blue Origin BE-4 engines that use Methane and LOX.

mind they still use the engines they have stockpiled, they just aren't taking delivery of new ones because of trade sanctions.

Yes, the Starliner was launched on an Atlas V rocket. The Atlas V is a launcher designed in the 90's, after the end of the cold war, so using a Russian engine on the first stage wasn't a big issue from a geopolitical perspective.
But in 2014 with the situation in Ukraine and Crimea, the United States Congress tried to push ULA (the launcher manufacturer) to stop using Russian engines. So ULA announced the development of a replacement launcher for the Atlas V that would rely only on American parts, the Vulcan Centaur.
Rocket developments are long and Vulcan only did its maiden flight in January of this year.
Even though the rocket is operational, it's clearly far from being considered by NASA as "Human rated" whereas the Atlas V is.
So, for now the Boeing Starliner is only planned to be launched by Atlas V. ULA cannot buy Russian engines anymore but they still have enough left to perform the last flights of the Atlas V including six Starliner launches.

The use of ex-Soviet (Russian and Ukrainian) engines was in a large part due to the geopolitical situation: it was an attempt to keep engineers employed so that they wouldn't go off and build missile engines for unfriendly countries.
